# Undefined error datatables jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using datatables along with extensions like Button, FixedColumns. My Script code is:

**jQuery:**

```
function getData(id)
    {
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#tableid"))
        {
            $("#tableid").DataTable().clear().destroy(false);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?= base_url(); ?>data/view/"+id,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.length==0)
                {
                    $("#overlay").fadeIn(500, function () {
                        $("#tableid_cont").css('visibility', "hidden");
                    });
                    //alert("No data in DB!");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#tableid").html(data);
                    initTable();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function initTable()
    {
        var table = $("#tableid").DataTable({
            scrollY: "100%",
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            fixedColumns: true,
            ordering: false,
            lengthChange: false,
            "bInfo": false,
            buttons: ['excel'],
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                $("#overlay").fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $("#tableid_cont").css('visibility', "visible");
                });
            }
        });
        table.buttons().container().appendTo('#action-buttons');
    }
```

The `getData()` is manipulated by an event `onchange` in select HTML element and the paramter `id` get some integer values. The return of the ajax will be a string containing the HTML table with id `tableid`.

Let my select values be `1,2,3`

I start calling `getData(1)` and this load and initializes the datatable fine with no issues. And if the values changes to `2` or `3` the error that I am getting is **Cannot read property 'dt' of undefined** and this occurs at the line `$("#tableid").DataTable().clear().destroy(false);`.

Then changing the values again, the table works fine with absolutely no error.

The conclusion I arrived is: after the datatable is initialied, the `destroy()` gets called and error occurs. But is actually destroyed. The another initialization can be done again, so error does not occur next time.

Am I doing anything wrong? I tried hard but cannot overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroy datatable, try reloading it is ajax by:

```
$('#tableid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Comment: My return is not `JSON` and used reload but error: `Cannot set property 'data' of null`